# ClassCastException: difference between "cannot be cast to class" and "incompatible with" message

Tags: java, classcastexception

It's clear, the following code can cause a ClassCastException:

```
Integer a = 1;
Object b = a;
Long c = (Long)b;
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long
                                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But in a server stacktrace I have a (likewise) message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer incompatible with java.lang.Long
                                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Current, I cannot reproduce this problem and it might even be a race condition. The code is too complex and too confidential to paste here, it's somewhere in a cascade of lambdas in generic functions. But for knowing what I have to look for, I want to understand this little difference in the message text.

What can cause such a "incompatible with" ClassCastException?

One thing I know is that this message can happen when casting arrays (`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String incompatible with [Ljava.lang.Object;`). But the two types I have in the message are simple POJO classes.

---

**Update:** Here's some anonymized code:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.x.model.stammdaten.TypeA incompatible with ch.x.model.stammdaten.TypeB
    at ch.x.validation.ValidatorEntityChooser$$Lambda$509/0x00000000c800f330.apply(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at ch.x.validation.ValidatorEntityChooser.lambda$addEntityChooser$6(ValidatorEntityChooser.java:119) ~[ch.stzh.egov.gwz-gwz-app-1.14.4.jar:?]
    at ch.x.validation.ValidatorEntityChooser$$Lambda$506/0x00000000c8242ed0.apply(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at ch.x.validation.ValidatorEntityChooser.lambda$addEntitiesChooser$7(ValidatorEntityChooser.java:124) ~[ch.stzh.egov.gwz-gwz-app-1.14.4.jar:?]
    at ch.x.validation.ValidatorEntityChooser$$Lambda$508/0x00000000c8241c60.apply(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at ch.x.validation.ValidatorEntityChooser.lambda$getValidationEntity$9(ValidatorEntityChooser.java:134) ~[ch.stzh.egov.gwz-gwz-app-1.14.4.jar:?]
    at ch.x.validation.ValidatorEntityChooser$$Lambda$1155/0x00000000cc066150.apply(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:204) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:204) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:186) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1567) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:524) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:514) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:719) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:245) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:510) ~[?:1.8.0]



   public static <T extends BaseEntityUUID> void addEntityChooser(
      Class<T> clazz, Function<T, ? extends BaseEntityUUID> chooser) {
119     addEntitiesChooser(clazz, t -> Collections.singleton(chooser.apply((T) t)));
  }

   public static <T extends BaseEntityUUID> void addEntitiesChooser(
      Class<T> clazz, Function<T, Collection<? extends BaseEntityUUID>> chooser) {
124    chooserFunctions.put(clazz::isInstance, t -> chooser.apply((T) t));
  }


  public List<BaseEntityUUID> getValidationEntity(BaseEntityUUID entity) {
    return chooserFunctions.keySet().stream()
        .filter(p -> p.test(entity))
        .map(chooserFunctions::get)
134     .map(f -> f.apply(entity))
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(toList());
  }
```

But in unit tests I can call getValidationEntity with TypeA and with TypeB, both without exception. And the code itself is part of the transaction handling and runs multiple 1000 times a day without problems. `chooserFunctions` is static and doesn't change. The exception happens (likely) when `getValidationEntity()` is called with `TypeA`, but `TypeA` is not even in the keySet of `chooserFunctions`.

And yes, maybe it's important: It's about Java 1.8

Comment: Could it just be a JVM difference? If you're not explicitly throwing the CCE, it's got to be coming from the JVM.

Comment: You'll have to look at the stack trace. Array component type checking was a good idea, but without stack trace (one would expect in the logs!) ....

Comment: @JoopEggen see text change

Comment: If you suspect race conditions, you should not use a `HashMap`. Generally, if you need key and value, iterate/stream over the `entrySet()` in the first place, instead of performing a map lookup for every key. Then, use `clazz.cast(t)` instead of performing an unchecked cast `(T)t`.

Comment: the point is that I have to understand why the current code fails. it's known that the HashMap doesn't change.

Comment: The error disappeared after restarting one of the two server instances. With the same source code, the same data, the same JRE etc I wasn't able to reproduce this error on any other machine. // the original question though is still open

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any difference in meaning.  It possibly happens because the versions of Java that generated the exceptions are different.  It possibly happens because the exceptions arise in different contexts; e.g. a `(<type-name>)` cast versus a reflective type cast.

<sup>I did a bit of source code trawling to see if I could figure out where the difference occurs.  In Java 17, the "cannot be cast to class" form is used in a regular typecast.  The "incompatible with" form doesn't appear to be used anywhere.  Or at least ... I find it using `find` and `grep`.  So I'm inclined to think it is a Java version thing.  Maybe even OpenJDK Java versus Android.</sup>

It is also possible that your code (or a 3rd party library) is throwing the exception explicitly with the unusual exception message.  Try looking at where the unusual version is being thrown.